# Lync Meeting URL expiration period

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010

I've created Lync meeting URL using Lync API 2010, and now I also want to set Lync URL expiration period using Lync api can anybody help me to solve it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expiry period is set in the [ConferenceScheduleInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.conferencemanagement.conferencescheduleinformation_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr(v=office.15).aspx) class.

You can either specify this when you create the conference, or you can update the conference passing in the updated ConferenceSCheduleInformation class using the [BeginUpdateConference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh383039(v=office.15).aspx) method.